# Unwanted line shows up in matlab 3d triplet line

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d

I am plotting 3d lines using MATLAB's `plot3` command.
I have arranged my data into X, Y, Z triplets to run through the function as such:
Where points is an array with 6 columns. 
The 1st three columns in row one are the coordinates of the i'th node of the 1st element. Similarly the 2nd three columns are the j'th node's coordinates.

```
points =
[x1   y1    z1    x2    y2    z2]
 0     0     0    60     0     0
60     0     0    90     0     0
60     0    30    60     0     0
60     0    30    60    30    30
60    30    30    60    30     0


plot3 ( [x1 ;x2] , [y1 ; y2] , [z1 ; z2], '-or')
```

With some other processing my result is this:
[image: Plot with extra line circled]

Looking closely at the points table, there is no such line that goes from between points [60 0 0] and [60 30 30]

Does anyone have any advice for how I might remove this unsightly artefact?
Note: The analysis using these elements and nodes are not affected, I suspect it is purely graphical.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are correct.  It is graphical.

The way MATLAB plots points is that it **connects** a line between successive points.  Therefore, it joins a line between points 1 and 2, then 2 and 3, 3 and 4, etc.

If you want to achieve what you want, so without the diagonal line, you'll need to plot the lines in a particular order.  What I would do is first plot the line parallel to the `z = 0` axis, then draw the square shape after.

```
%// Draw parallel line
plot3([90 0], [0 0], [0 0], '-or');

%// Draw square shape
x = [60 60 60 60];
y = [0 0 30 30];
z = [0 30 30 0];

hold on;
plot3(x, y, z, '-or');
axis ij; %// Invert y axis
```

Take a look at how I defined the square shape.  I started from the left of the shape, then traced around in a clockwise manner.  I first plot the parallel line, then the square shape after.

This is what I get:

[image]

Comment: Rayryeng Thanks alot! Your solution makes sense and is very helpful for this isolated case. But now!! The points that I want to draw could be any number and in many arrangements, so is there some kind of rule that I could follow to guarantee that the lines drawn are only between the points that I specify? I suppose I could write a for loop that plots each line individually while holding.... I wonder if there is a more elegant way.

Comment: The thing is that I don't know what your shape is supposed to look like in a general sense so I can't suggest anything.  Basically, remember that pairs of consecutive points when invoking `plot` has lines drawn in between them.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to plot a system of links that are between nodes, connections are made at nodes, both links and nodes are defined explicitly. For example, one must have nodes1 N1 and N2 to create a link L1(N1,N2). I form this information into an array where row1 = [N1 N2] where N contains a 3 column vector with the cartesian coordinate. I have partitioned out the X,Y,Z vectors from this matrix and attempted to pass them all together into the plot3 command. As shown in a simple case, this lead to the plot of another line segment that was unintentional (frankly I am still not clear as to why). The surefire way that I have found is by looping over the X,Y,Z vectors and plotting the segments individually.

```
hold on
for i = 1:length(x1)
    plot3 ( [x1(i) ;x2(i)] , [y1(i) ; y2(i)] ,[z1(i);z2(i)], '-or')
end
hold off
```

[image]